# Facebook share_open_graph error on share

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I'm trying to perform a share_open_graph through my facebook app but I get an error when I try to share or when clicking on the share dialog if I use a different url to get past the first error.

Here's the code I use to share:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'share_open_graph',
    action_type: 'og.shares',
    action_properties: JSON.stringify({
        object: {
            'og:title': caption,
            'og:description': description,
            'og:image': picture,
            'og:url': link
        }
    })
    }, function(response){
        ...
    }
);
```

If `link` is `apps.facebook.com/appName` then when trying to share there is an 
[error (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqYV6.png)

If I change the link to my server's url which my facebook app targets, I get an [error (Image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY3JR.png) when I click on the shared post. The url in the error dialog is the `apps.facebook.com/appName`. I'm not sure why.

Facebook API version is 2.5, but I'm not sure this could be the issue as posts seem to work on our test app, which is also at version 2.5, but is in development mode.

Comment: Can we assume that you used proper, absolute URLs, and not just relative paths (which of course won’t work, or either make sense in the first place) …?

Comment: Yeah I use the full url for `link`

Comment: Can you show an actual example please?

Comment: While trying to get an actual example, I found this issue has fixed itself. it seems facebook broke something in their back and end and fixed it because this has been working for a while and randomly stops. I'm closing this question.